# @PostConstruct initializer runs before Spock setup() metod, can't mock service in time

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I have a service (A) that I'm writing a Spock unit-test for. This service uses an `init()`-method, annotated with `@PostConstruct` which calls another service (B) method.

My problem is that the `init()` method seems to be called before the Spock `setup()` method, so I get a `NullPointerException` from `init()` as my service B is `null` (not mocked yet). How can I solve this?

**Service A to be tested:**

```java
class MasseJournaliseringService {

    BeskedModtagerService beskedModtagerService
    SagslagerIntegrationService sagslagerIntegrationService
    ExecutorService executorService

    private static String s9identity = ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.MASSEUDSENDELSESMODUL_FAGSYSTEM_ENTITETSID) as String
    private Principal udfoertAf
    List<Future<String>> futures = []

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        udfoertAf = sagslagerIntegrationService.opretPrincipal(s9identity) // NullPointerException!!
        int corePoolSize = ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.MSG_BROKER_MU_JOURNALISER_COREPOOLSIZE) as int
        int maxPoolSize = ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.MSG_BROKER_MU_JOURNALISER_POOLSIZE) as int
        int queueCapacity = ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.MSG_BROKER_MU_JOURNALISER_QUEUE_CAPACITY) as int
        int keepAliveTime = ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.MSG_BROKER_MU_JOURNALISER_KEEPALIVETIME) as int
        this.executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueCapacity),
                new CustomizableThreadFactory(threadNamePrefix: 'mu-journ-'))
    }
}
```

**Spock unit-test:**

```java
package beskedfordeler.core.service.broker

import beskedfordeler.core.configuration.ConfigHelper
import beskedfordeler.core.configuration.ConfigNoegler
import beskedfordeler.core.helpers.MasseudsendelseLogHelper
import beskedfordeler.core.service.domain.BeskedModtagerService
import beskedfordeler.core.service.integration.SagslagerIntegrationService
import grails.testing.services.ServiceUnitTest
import org.grails.spring.beans.factory.InstanceFactoryBean
import spock.lang.Specification

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
import java.util.concurrent.Future
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

class MasseJournaliseringServiceSpec extends Specification implements ServiceUnitTest<MasseJournaliseringService> {

    def setup() {
        GroovyMock(ConfigHelper, global: true)
        ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.BF_FAGSYSTEM_ENTITETSID) >> "FAGSYSTEM"
        ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.MYNDIGHED_ERST) >> "MYNDIGHED"
        ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.MASSEUDSENDELSESMODUL_FAGSYSTEM_ENTITETSID) >> "FAGSYSTEM_ID"
        service.sagslagerIntegrationService = Mock(SagslagerIntegrationService) // BeanCreationException caused by NullPointerException
        service.beskedModtagerService = Mock(BeskedModtagerService)
        ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.MSG_BROKER_MU_JOURNALISER_COREPOOLSIZE) >> 5
        ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.MSG_BROKER_MU_JOURNALISER_POOLSIZE) >> 5
        ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.MSG_BROKER_MU_JOURNALISER_QUEUE_CAPACITY) >> 10
        ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.MSG_BROKER_MU_JOURNALISER_KEEPALIVETIME) >> 60
    }

    // Test cases...
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to provide config values for the CUT?

Comment: Your test does not seem to use the [`spock-spring` module](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1/all_in_one.html#_spring_module). I am not seeing any `org.spockframework.spring.**` imports. Have you considered using it? I am not a Spring user, but I know the module is designed to help you to better integrate with Spring, e.g. injecting mocks, auto-wire Spring components into Spock tests, enabling mocks for scoped beans.

Comment: You can try to make service (A) lazy.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings how would I do that? I'm guessing you mean changing the source implementation... :/